# react native, map is not loading

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using `react-native-locationView` lib, but map is not loading as shown in image below.
I'm using it so user can set it's location. Below is my code for it
function to update address

```
 const updateAddress = (data) => {
    console.log('enter==>>');
    setState({
      ...state,
      location: data.address,
      userLoc: {
        latitude: data.latitude,
        longitude: data.longitude,
      },
      // zipCode: zipCode || null,
    });
    console.log('coordinates==>>>>>', userLoc);
    onCloseLocation();
  };
```

that's the modal, here I'm using LocationView

```
<Modal animationType="slide" visible={locationModal}>
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
          <PressImage
            source={imagePath.crossBtn}
            style={{
              alignSelf: 'center',
              marginVertical: moderateScaleVertical(10),
            }}
            onPress={onCloseLocation}
          />
          <LocationView
            apiKey={GOOGLE_MAP_KEY}
            initialLocation={{
              latitude: userLoc.latitude,
              longitude: userLoc.longitude,
            }}
            onLocationSelect={(data) => updateAddress(data)}
          />
        </View>
      </Modal>
```

can someone tell why map is not loading properly? Please Help

[image]